# Why can't I import anything of pyjnius besides jnius?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, pyjnius

When I use the python interpreter I can import it just fine. But if I write a script, for some reason `import jnius` works fine but when I write `from jnius import autoclass` or `from jnius import JavaClass` I get an `ImportError: Cannot import 'autoclass' from 'jnius'`.

I've even tried writing

```
import jnius
Python Activity = jnius.autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
```

but I get `AttributeError:  'jnius' has no attribute 'autoclass'`.

**Edit:**
While we're on the `autoclass` topic, when I write

```
Python Activity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')
```

I get

```
jnius.JavaException: Class not found b'org/kivy/android/PythonActivity'
```

Comment: Could it be a python2/3 issue? Which interpreter do you use when it works, and which interpreter is called for the script? You could print `sys.version` (if I remember correctly).

Comment: I'm using python 3.7.3, I don't have another intepreter that executes the script

Comment: Are you sure? Did you check with `sys.version` (that would be on top of the list which I would check). Are you doing the same thing in the interpreter that you do in the script? Did you try it in a newly opened interpreter? Generally it should be in `sys.path` or `PYTHONPATH`

Comment: I did use ```sys.version``` as soon as I saw you comment. It said the version's 3.7.3. Where can I find ```PYTHONPATH```?

Comment: `PYTHONPATH` is an environment variable you set, i.e. launch your script (or interpreter) with `$ PYTHONPATH=/path/to/some/modules python # or add script.py here` (you don't need `$` that just marks the usual bash prompt, in windows it'd be something like `C:\...\>`), but I'd start with checking `sys.path`, and even earlier, launching a new/fresh python interpreter and try including what you want there. If it works from the interpreter, it should work from the script. There is no dilemma there... how did you include the things in the interpreter? Can you do it again?

Comment: so `PYTHONPATH` is more or less same as `sys.path` and these are the directories python uses to look for modules it would import... and also if you use something custom, in the current directory, you might need to write something like `PYTHONPATH=. python script.py`. Now that you mention it, it might be that the interpreter includes `.` (current dir) into the path, while running a script doesn't...

Comment: I'm still getting the same results

Comment: Ok, just to confirm. If you type `from jnius import autoclass` into the interpreter it works and doesn't give any errors. If you run a script with `from jnius import autoclass` you get `AttributeError:  'jnius' has no attribute 'autoclass'`? Still, I'd check the `sys.path` in both cases. How are you launching the script, and how are you launching the interpreter?

Comment: It's actually ```ImportError: Cannot import 'autoclass' from jnius``` when I type ```from jnius import autoclass ```, but I've solved it. I get ```AttributeError``` when I type ```PythonActivity = jnius.autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')```. Did you see the **Edit** part of the problem? That's the one I'm trying to fix now

Comment: Are you actually running htis code on Android?

Comment: If you named one of your own files `jnius.py`, or named a folder `jnius`, pick a different name.

Comment: What is the name of the script you created?

Comment: @user2357112 hehe. That's what I actually named the file. When I deleted it in a panic induced rage, it fixed the first problem. But I still have `jnius.JavaException: Class not found b'org/kivy/android/PythonActivity`

Answer (score 2):

OP here.

I did check and everything was set up correctly. I just did not realize that I had to import kivy first before importing jnius.

The code should look something like the one below if you want to test it. I've only tried it on my android phone using Pydroid3 and I haven't tried it on my laptop

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

from jnius import autoclass


PythonActivity = autoclass('org.kivy.android.PythonActivity')

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text=str(type(PythonActivity)))


if __name__=="__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

It should show the following line`<class 'jnius.jnius.MetaJavaClass'>`